# Adding a segue to another view controller when specific action is picked from a popup

Tags: ios, swift, popup, alert

I'm trying to link a specific View Controller that will run when the user picks 'yes' off of a different pop up automatically generated after a random number is chosen.

How would I add the second view controller only when the user picks yes (and discards the pop up when the user picks no)?

I researched it on Stack already and someone suggested using Storyboard and Segues, so I have connected the first and second view controllers using "Show Segue to Weapon Pop Up View Controller", and the second VC has the storyboard ID of "PopUp".

Thanks for any help!

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func rolld20(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomnumber20 = Int.random(in: 1...20)
        d20label.text = String(randomnumber20)

        //create the alert
        let d20alert = UIAlertController(title: "You rolled a D20!",
        message: "You rolled a \(String(randomnumber20))! Is this enough?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        // add the actions (yes/no buttons)
        d20alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)) {
            //code to open up second view controller with the storyboard ID "PopUp" goes here I believe?
        }
        d20alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))

        // show the alert when the user clicks to roll d20
        self.present(d20alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

In your case, the code would be something like:

```
@IBAction func rolld20(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomnumber20 = Int.random(in: 1...20)
    let d20alert = UIAlertController(title: "You rolled a D20!",
    message: "You rolled a \(String(randomnumber20))! Is this enough?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    d20alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style:  .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PopUp", sender: nil)
     }))
    d20alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(d20alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I removed the comments for readability. Have in mind that the string `identifier` in the method is relative to the SEGUE identifier, not the destination view controller identifier. To set your segue identifier, simply click on the segue:

[image]

And edit the identifier on "Show the Attributes inspector" item:

[image]

Comment: Ok! I added the code and edited the segue (thanks, i think i understand it a bit better now), but I'm getting an error on my d20alert.addAction yes line, which states: Cannot invoke 'addAction' with an argument list of type '(UIAlertAction, @escaping () -> Void)'. Any idea what this means/how to fix it?

Comment: There was an issue on the action return method. Check the edit, should work fine now.